# React360 npm install stuck at Loading dependency graph

Tags: react-native, react-360

I have to do some work with VR for a uni project and I installed the React360 cli for this. I then ran react-360 init Hello360, cd Hello360. The files are all installed and fine

The issue is when I try to start the local server with npm start. Once I type enter I see what is below and nothing else. its stuck. Can anyone help me isolate the issue?

```
> Hello360@0.0.1 start /Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360
> node node_modules/react-360/scripts/packager.js

open browser at http://localhost:8081/index.html


Starting React Native Packager...
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph...(node:8286) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)
    at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360/node_modules/sane/src/fsevents_watcher.js:41:11)
    at createWatcher (/Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:572:23)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HasteMap._watch (/Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:683:44)
    at /Users/kishokanthjeganathan/Documents/Final-Code/VR/Hello360/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:280:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:8286) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8286) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here. Hope this helps!

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/854#issuecomment-343243804